# Symfony 3.3.10 большая нагрузка на CPU

Tags: symfony3, php-fpm

Очень большая нагрузка на цп под стек - nginx + php-7.1-fpm +symfony 3
при http реквесте к серверу

цп сильно грузи процесс php-fpm pool www

что в dev, что в prod

Comment: А вы, точно уверены, что это `Symfony`? А не настройки вашего веб сервера или куда хуже атака? Да и вообще вопрос не понятный, нет кода, который по вашему мнению грузит цп.

Comment: Симфони из коробки, без стороннего кода.
Так же php-fpm и nginx из коробки, заметил во время разработки.
Изумился, задал вот  таковй вот вопрос, может что подскажите

Comment: Просто поставьте на нормальный хост и проверьте работоспособность - этого *** `Symfony` - вообще не рекомендую этот хлам использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У нас была похожая проблема, мы замени пути вида `/root/path/app/../src` на `/root/path/src` (то есть без `/../` в пути)

Я точно не знаю в чем именно заключается проблема, но наши devops'ы сообщили о том, что из-за путей с `/../` на каждый кусочек пути php7 проверяет существования этого пути, а по таким путям загружались все конфиги, шаблоны и идет большая нагрузка на ЦП.

Так же стоит сделать оптимизацию автолоадинга в Composer'е.

Comment: Забавно, но именно замена относительный путей на статику помогло существенно снизить нагрузку. Интересно конечно... даже не думал что в этом может быть проблема.

Comment: я рад что смог вам помочь